# Chart JS not showing On hover with small data

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

If I have large data with small data in Bar chart, small data are not showing in onhover function.
Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/ramakrishnap/zju8044k/
Ex:

```
//Bar chart for Broadcasts data
                    var broadcastData = {
                        labels : ['01-29-15','01-30-15','01-31-15','02-01-15','02-02-15','02-03-15','02-04-15','02-05-15','02-06-15','02-07-15','02-08-15','02-09-15','02-10-15','02-11-15','02-12-15'],
                        datasets : [
                        {
                            label: "Opt-In",
                            fillColor : "#4e8eb1",
                            strokeColor : "#9b9b9b",
                            pointColor : "#fff",
                            pointStrokeColor : "#990000",
                            data : [3,3,6,3,4,6,6,47079,8,11,5,5,13,10,]
                        }
                    ]
                    }
                     // get Bar chart canvas
                    var broadcasts = document.getElementById('broadcast').getContext('2d');
                    // draw Bar chart
                    new Chart(broadcasts).Bar(broadcastData);
```

Comment: To me it looks like a bug in the library itself. I suggest you to post a bug report on the git repository of the library : https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues . Include a link to your jsfiddle and eventually to this SO thread. That will help them pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Added Thanks. There are many issues open.

Comment: There are many indeed. There's also much pull and commit activity and several contributors. So I'd say opening a bug report is very much worth a try. Else, if you feel like it, you can fork the repository, try and fix the bug and contribute your fix back...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

try adding commonSeriesSettings property to your chart

> commonSeriesSettings: {
>
> hoverMode: 'includePoints',    selectionMode: 'includePoints',
>
> }

Comment: Oh, I thought you mean onHover cannot show all figures. I get what you mean now. 

Just enlarged the canvas, and you should see the small figure now. Seems because the bar is too small to detect the hover.

Comment: Yes, Is there any way to show for small values onHover.

Answer (score 0):

If **intersect** is set to true, the tooltip mode applies only when the mouse position intersects with an element. If **false**, the mode will be applied at all times. more about tooltip configuration is [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#:%7E:text=Tooltip%20Configuration)

```
const options = {
      plugins: {
        tooltip: {
          interaction:{
            intersect: false,
          },
        },
      },
    };
```